# when i define property of fonts in h2 tag my text got overlapped on each other

Tags: html, css

I define this property to h2 tag and it the text got overlap on each other. I applied padding of 7% to top and bottom and 15% to left and right to the section class.

```css
h2{
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
#testimonials{
  padding: 7% 15%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ef8172;
  color: #fff;

}
```

```html
  <section id="testimonials">

    <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
    <img src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
    <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

    <!-- <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em> -->

  </section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not only defined the font size (3rem) but you have also specified the line height (1.7rem). Your specified line height is smaller than the 'natural' line height of the 3rem font.

If you don't specify a line height then the default will be selected and characters won't overlap. line-height is the whole height, not just the space between lines.

```css
h2{
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  /*line-height: 1.5rem;*/
}
#testimonials{
  padding: 7% 15%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ef8172;
  color: #fff;

}
```

```html
  <section id="testimonials">

    <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
    <img src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
    <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

    <!-- <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
    <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
    <em>Beverly, Illinois</em> -->

  </section>
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the - **h2{line-height: 1.5rem;}**
Increase the line-height to 2rem and it'll be fixed